# Unable to get any linting done in github's atom editor (using Linter + Linter Pylint)

Tags: github, editor, pylint, atom-editor

Text Editor: Atom v 0.140.0

```
Installed version of Linter: 0.7.3
Installed version of Linter Pylint: 0.1.5
Version of Atom: 0.140.0
Running on Linux Mint 16
Pylint version: pylint 0.26.0, 
astng 0.24.1, common 0.59.1
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1]
```

**Issue:** Both the packages (linter and linter pylint) are installed and enabled but no linting is being done in case of errors.
For example
`priont "asdf"` doesn't show any kind of error message.

Comment: Did you close your project and reopen after installing the packages?

Comment: @AJGregory Yes, I have tried many times, complete reinstalls after deleting the configuration files, etc. Reopened `Atom` with sudo, etc. But nothing works. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: The only other suggestion i could make is to try a linter for another language to see if the issue is with Pylint. I use Linter with Linter Ruby and Coffeelint and both worked fine after reopening the project. Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance!

Comment: @AJGregory I tried with java too but no linting is being done. Can you check your config for me? "Edit menu -> Open your config". Is there any linting options there? I have `'linter': {}`. Nothing inside it. I tried putting `pylint` and `linter-pylint` inside it but they don't work either and give error in the console. And thank you for trying.

Comment: My config file looks the same. `'linter': {}`

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem on Windows 8 but was able to fix it by **editing the config.cson file in Atom**. After you've downloaded your linters, you need to first get the full path (file location) for the linter. Then, go into the config.cson file and you should see all the linters you've downloaded somewhere in the file. For example, I was trying to get pylint to work. In the config file there should be quotations containing your specific linter somewhere in the file, for example, mine has a line of code that just read:

```
"linter-pylint": {}
```

Delete the brackets, and in the line under the name of your linter (keep the colon and it should auto indent the next line) add `"path: "` and then the full path name of your linter. So I changed my pylint to

```
"linter-pylint":
  path: "C:Users/Student/.atom/packages/linter-pylint"
```

then I restarted Atom and the linter was working just fine. The same method worked for the C++ linter clang.

Note: you also might need to do the same thing for the generic linter itself; i.e. your file might contain a line that just says

```
"linter": {}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. All I did was add path to config.cson file in Atom.
Also, I had error with Error: spawn pylint which got fixed by installing pylint in widows using the command pip -install pylint

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you ever solved this, or you are still interested, but I ran into the same problem recently and solved it by downgrading the linter version.

Just run `apm install linter@1.2.4`

There was an issue opened at the github page: https://github.com/atom-community/linter/issues/815

Comment: linter-pylint has been upgraded to the latest API by the way.